# Spark SQL / Scala - Calculate Minute winner based on number of seconds watched in a given minute

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I would like to calculate minute winner based on number of seconds watched in a given minute. Below is an example of start_timestamp and end_timestamp. Eventually I will need to assign the minute to the channel with highest seconds in that minute.

| start_timestamp | end_timestamp | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7:59:45 | 8:00:09 | A |
| 8:00:10 | 8:00:14 | B |
| 8:00:15 | 8:00:29 | A |
| 8:00:30 | 8:02:10 | C |

In this example I am trying to which channel won the minute from 8:00:00 to 8:01:00. In this example channel A was watched 9+14=25 seconds. Channel B was watched 4 seconds and Channel C was watched 30 seconds. So channel C wins the minute and output looks like this. Same for the next event too.

| start_timestamp | end_timestamp | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00:00 | 8:01:00 | C |
| 8:01:00 | 8:02:00 | C |

Is there any algorithm or logic in SQL or Scala that can handle these?

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning - it might be a very badly-performing solution, depending on how long the time difference is for each row. The idea is to generate a sequence of timestamps in seconds, and count them using a group by window.

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "Channel",
    "explode(sequence(timestamp(start_timestamp), timestamp(end_timestamp), interval 1 second)) time"
).groupBy(window($"time", "1 minute"), $"Channel")
 .count()
 .groupBy("window")
 .agg(max(struct("count", "Channel")).as("s"))
 .select("window.*", "s.Channel")
 .orderBy("window")

df2.show(false)
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|start              |end                |Channel|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|2021-01-19 07:59:00|2021-01-19 08:00:00|A      |
|2021-01-19 08:00:00|2021-01-19 08:01:00|C      |
|2021-01-19 08:01:00|2021-01-19 08:02:00|C      |
|2021-01-19 08:02:00|2021-01-19 08:03:00|C      |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```